# Is there any C libsrtp function which only verifies and not decrypts the srtp packets?

Tags: c, rtp

Had to just verify AEAD tags of encrypted packet and drop it if not correct and forward without decrypting if correct.

Just searched over all srtp functions in opensource libsrtp C source code, but I could not see any such function which does only verification and not decrypt it.

Is there any function really available or it needs to be implemented?

According to below link: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-avtcore-srtp-aes-gcm-17#page-39 There is an algorithm of verifying decrypted packet which I am not seeing anywhere in srtp open source code. All I see is main function srtp_unprotect which in turn calls srtp_unprotect_aead for AES GCM decryption. But not able to find function which only verifies the AEAD tag

Comment: Not sure this will help you, but look about 1/3 the way down _[this article](https://pike.lysator.liu.se/docs/ietf/rfc/43/rfc4383.xml)_.  The discussion looks related.

Comment: According to below link:
https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtcore-srtp-aes-gcm-17#page-39

There is an algorithm of verifying decrypted packet which I am not seeing anywhere in srtp open source code. All I see is main function srtp_unprotect which in turn calls srtp_unprotect_aead for AES GCM decryption. But not able to find only tag verification function

Comment: Your comment contains useful information, and relevant context to the discussion.  As an option to using a comment, you can also append content such as this at the end of your post.  (potential contributers always look at the post, but not always at the comments.)